# Retrieve and modify HTML div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an asynchronous javascript function that sets the innerHMTL property of a div like so:

```js
async function getProductsRecommendationsAsync(){
    const product = await ...
    const mySection = document.querySelector(".my-section");
    mySection.innerHTML = renderProduct(product);
}

function renderProduct(product){
    return [
    '<div>',
    '<a href="' + productUrl + '" class="product__anchor">',
    '<img class="product__img" src="' + product.image + '" alt="'+ product.title +'"/>',
    '<p class="product__title">' + product.title + '</p>',
    '</a>',
    '</div>'
  ].join("");
}
```

In HTML I have a product (same structure as above) and the div the function modifies:

```html
<div class="product">
<a href="..." class="product__anchor">
<img class="product__img" src="..."/>
<p class="product__title">'Trousers'</p>
</a>
</div>

<div class="my-section"></div>
```

I want to avoid duplicating the code for rendering a product in two places. **How can I retrieve the HTML from the `product` div in the `renderProduct` javascript function and modify it's values?** In the real usecase, the code for rendering a product is over 300 lines of HTML.

Comment: Can you explain more? As I understood, you have a function `getProductsRecommendationsAsync`  in which you render elements into an hardcoded element(s): `.my-section`. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I write the HTML for rendering the product element in two places. I want to reuse the HTML I've already written in the div with class `product` in the function `renderProduct`.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove static HTML code and move everything to Javascript. For the initialization code, you could also handle load event of your window.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not to duplicate in static HTML the structure that can be rendered in a JS function.

So why not remove the static HTML of the product and instead on load invoke this Javascript to set up the first product 'Trousers'.

```
const mySection = document.querySelector(".my-section");
const initialProduct = {"title": "Trousers", "Url": theurl, "image": theimage};
mySection.innerHTML = renderProduct(initialProduct);
```

Note: I've assumed that productUrl in the given code should actually be product.Url, but this needs alteration if not.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, as I understood, you have some `div.mySection` elements. You did succeeded to load with the data. But - I suppose you hava a standalone element: `div.product` that you also want to load with data using `renderProduct` function.

The problem is that in `renderProduct` function you generate a non-classed div element, but you do want a class in this standalone element. In this case, I reckon on changing `renderProduct` a bit.

```
function renderProduct(product){
    return [
    '<a href="' + productUrl + '" class="product__anchor">',
    '<img class="product__img" src="' + product.image + '" alt="'+ product.title +'"/>',
    '<p class="product__title">' + product.title + '</p>',
    '</a>',
  ].join("");
}
```

Then, `getProductsRecommendationsAsync` would be:

```
async function getProductsRecommendationsAsync(){
    const product = await ...
    const mySection = document.querySelector(".my-section");
    mySection.innerHTML = `<div>${renderProduct(product)}</div>`;
}
```

Then load your standalone product with:

```
<div class="product">
</div>
```

Then, with JS target this element by any way you wish to:

```
const productStandaloneElement = ..
productStandaloneElement.innerHTML = renderProduct(product);
```